# .net MCV makes use of constructors without method bodies, How is this possible and how can it be duplicated?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

In an MVC app there are several classes that use constructors without a method body.  For instance one of the classes is the ActionResult class:

```
using System;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    // Summary:
    //     Encapsulates the result of an action method and is used to perform a framework-level
    //     operation on behalf of the action method.
    public abstract class ActionResult
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult class.
        protected ActionResult();

        // Summary:
        //     Enables processing of the result of an action method by a custom type that
        //     inherits from the System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult class.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   context:
        //     The context in which the result is executed. The context      information includes
        //     the controller, HTTP content, request context, and route data.
        public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
    }
}
```

This class constructor does not have a method body.
When I try and duplicate the code in an application I get the expected error saying that the constructor needs to have a method body.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;


    public abstract class MyBase
    {
        protected MyBase();
    }
}
```

What is Microsoft doing in this case to make the object constructors work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to the definition of a type that is outside of your project (like in a referenced library) what you see is the *metadata* of the *type*, an preview with the members that contains.

All those members are indeed implemented (except abstracts of cource) using regular *C#* syntax.

There are tools like *Reflector* that add extensions to *Visual Studio* and allows you decompile and see the actual code.

Comment: So to clarify, Metadata is a representation of the code, not the actual code?

Comment: yes, what you see isn't the real code, just the definition of the type.

Comment: Ok Thank you this answers my question.